# Contra/covariance and nested generics

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance, strong-typing

I have a question on typing and contra/covairance.

Given the following classes

```
public class BoardItemsHolderRepository<THolder, TBoardItem> : DataRepository<IList<THolder>> 
    where TBoardItem : BoardItem
    where THolder : IBoardItemHolder<TBoardItem>
{
}
```

```
public interface IDataRepository<T> : IDataGetRepository<T>, IDataSetRepository<T> where T : class
{
}

public interface IDataGetRepository<out T> where T : class
{
    IObservable<T> GetObservableStream();
    IObservable<T> GetMostRecent();
}

public interface IDataSetRepository<in T> where T : class
{
    void Set(T value);
}

public abstract class DataRepository<T> : IDataRepository<T> where T : class
{
  ..implementation details
}
```

```
public class ConstructHolder : IBoardItemHolder<Construct>
{
  ..implementation details
}
```

Given the above 3 files, can someone explain to me why is the following happening?:

```
IDataGetRepository<IList<IBoardItemHolder<Construct>>> wontCompile = new BoardItemsHolderRepository<ConstructHolder, Construct>(); //illegal
IDataGetRepository<IList<ConstructHolder>> compile = new BoardItemsHolderRepository<ConstructHolder, Construct>();  //legal
```

I can't understand why implicit casting for the first line would not work, as the following line compiles(as expected)

```
IBoardItemHolder<Construct>> compile = new ConstructHolder();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's expand the right hand side of the illegal line step by step. First, we start with

```
BoardItemsHolderRepository<ConstructHolder, Construct>
```

This is a `DataRepository<IList<THolder>>`, so the above is a kind of:

```
DataRepository<IList<ConstructHolder>>
```

which in turn is `IDataGetRepository<T>`, so the above is a kind of:

```
IDataGetRepository<IList<ConstructHolder>>
```

`IDataGetRepository<T>` is covariant on `T`. Recall exactly what this means: **If** `U` is a subtype of `T`, then `IDataGetRepository<U>` is a subtype of `IDataGetRepository<T>`. For example, `IDataGetRepository<Cat>` is a subtype of `IDataGetRepository<Animal>`, and so an instance of the former type can be assigned to a variable of the latter type.

However, `IDataGetRepository<IList<ConstructHolder>>` is not a subtype of `IDataGetRepository<IList<IBoardItemHolder<Construct>>>` and so cannot be assigned to it. Why? **Because `IList<ConstructHolder>` is not a subtype of `IList<IBoardItemHolder<Construct>>`! `IList<T>` is invariant on `T`!**

So what you are trying to do violates type safety, according to the type-checker. Maybe try using a `IEnumerable` rather than `IList`?